# what does "::'variable'" refer to?

Tags: c++, scope

what does ::i mean in the below program?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i = 10;
int main(){
   int i = 20;
   {
   int i = 30;
   cout << i << ::i <<endl;
   }
}
```

It outputs "3010". "::i" seems to be referring to the global declaration. What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 9):

It is called as **Qualified Name lookup.**
It referes to the variable `i` declared at global scope.
Simply it means don't refer the local variable `i` if any but refer the `i` in global scope.

Whenever you have same named variables in the local scope, When referring to the variable name the preference is given to the variable in the local scope. This means in your program, the `i` inside the local scope `{` `}` hides all the other variables named `i` namely the ones(`i=20` as well as `i=10`). So to refer the `i`, which is in the global scope, you use the `::` scope resolution operator.=

Comment: Maybe you could also address that the first local `i` is hidden by the second one; the OP might wonder why `::i` isn't getting the outer local `i`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Oh, rather late in replying the comment but that's done. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Variables and functions which starts with `::` operator describes that this variable or function is in the global namespace (not local). In your example `i` means local variable which defined at 7th line and `::i` means global one which defined at 3rd line. But `i` does not refer to outer local variable which is defined at 5th line because it's redefined and inaccessible in that scope (line 6 to 9).

Answer (score 3):

The `::` operator is the [scope resolution operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc05cplr175.htm). When you write `scopename::name` it means that you are referring to the object/function/... named `name` into the scope `scopename` (usually a namespace); e.g., if you didn't write `using namespace std;` to use `cin`/`cout`/... you would have to write `std::cin`/`std::cout`/...

If the scope resolution operator isn't preceded by a scope name, it means that you're explicitly referring to an object put into the global namespace, as the global `i` is in your program.

This is particularly useful if you have currently imported several namespaces (using the `using namespace` directive) or have local names that hide the global ones. In your code, this is exactly what happens: the local `i` "hides" the global one, and you need the `::` to access the global `i`.

*Random tip*: you'll often see `::` used to refer to global identifiers when you're dealing with C libraries (that have no notion of namespaces) and you want to be sure you're calling a particular C function instead of some C++ method that hides it into the current scope (this happens a lot in MFC code that wants to call Windows APIs).

Comment: @Macke: it just popped in my mind while writing the answer; actually, it's the only instance I saw where the `::` operator is used a lot to refer to stuff in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

`i` at the global namespace.

```
{
  int i = 30;
  cout << i << ::i <<endl;

  // 1. First i refers to the block scoped i having value 30
  // 2. ::i refers to the global variable i having the value 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`::i` refers to the `i` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a scoping operator. It is generally used for namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

`::i` refers to the global variable.

`::` is used for global namespace. So `::i` means the variable `i` declared at global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

`::i` means search for `i` which is not nested in anything. In your case this will be refering to `i=10;`  Also [see c/c++ search wildcard and syntax](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/SDK_doc/concepts/cdt_c_search.htm).